# JavaFX Can I use swing node in raspberry pi?

Tags: java, javafx, raspberry-pi

In my aplication I used swingNode and when I start aplication in raspberry i see this :

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.embed.swing.SwingNode
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 13 more
```

Comment: Do other classes from JavaFx work?

Comment: @Clayn when I delete this I see Failed to create EGLContextGraphics Device initialization failed for :  es2
Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found